# Converting factor date time columns into POSIXct in R

Tags: r

I have another problem. I have a date time column in a data frame, which when i upload it comes as factor and I want it to be POSIXct

```
str(ida$DATA_TRAMA)
 Factor w/ 1122932 levels "1-1-2010 00:00:51",..: 629101 629120 629128 629132 629139 629149
```

And i want it to be POSIXct (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S) format. I already tried all of these methods but none of them seem to work. Whichever i apply it gets NA values.

```
ida$DATA_TRAMA<- as.POSIXct(ida$DATA_TRAMA,format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

ida$DATA_TRAMA<- as.POSIXct(as.character(ida$DATA_TRAMA), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") 
ida$DATA_TRAMA <-format(ida$DATA_TRAMA, "%Y-%m-%d")
ida$DATA_TRAMA <- as.POSIXct(ida$DATA_TRAMA, format = '%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S')

ida$DATA_TRAMA <- as.POSIXlt(as.character(ida$DATA_TRAMA), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

ida$DATA_TRAMA <- strptime(ida$DATA_TRAMA,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct(as.character(ida$DATA_TRAMA), format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")` and it should also work without `as.character` , `as.POSIXct(ida$DATA_TRAMA, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With a `"factor"` argument `as.POSIXct` will invoke `as.POSIXct.default` and that uses `as.POSIXlt` which has a `"factor"` method so just do:

```
DF <- data.frame(d = "1-1-2010 00:00:51") # test data. d has factor class.
transform(DF, d = as.POSIXct(d, format = "%m-%d-%Y %T"))
```

giving:

```
                    d
1 2010-01-01 00:00:51
```